# How I get AJAX respond result back to main page

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

I have a user registration form in a jQuery modal dialog.

After completing the form and clicking on the button of the modal dialog, the data should go to mysql. That part is ok for me. I am using Jquery/Ajax to send the data to the database.

My problem is that I need to get back the processed data to my main page, user.php (where the modal dialog is opened). There is a table that displays all registered users and I wish to update that HTML table to show a successful registration.

This is my Jquery/Ajax -

```
    if ( bValid) { 

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
            url: "process.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
            //dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { 
                name: $('#name').val(), 
                address: $('#address').val(), 
                city: $('#city').val() 
            },
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                //On error, we alert user
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
        $(this).dialog("close");                    
    }
```

This is PHP code from process.php page

```
<?php
//include db configuration file
include_once("../test.php");

if ( (isset($_POST["name"]) && strlen($_POST["name"]) >= 3 && strlen($_POST["name"]) <= 60) &&
    (isset($_POST["address"]) && strlen($_POST["address"]) >= 3 && strlen($_POST["address"]) <= 50) &&
    (isset($_POST["city"]) && strlen($_POST["city"]) >= 3 && strlen($_POST["city"]) <= 40) ) 
{   //check $_POST["name"] and $_POST["address"] and $_POST["city"] are not empty

    $name   = $_POST["name"];
    $address = $_POST["address"];
    $city   = $_POST["city"];

    $q = "INSERT INTO users ( name, address, city) VALUES 
            ('".$name."','".$address."','".$city."')";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q); 

    if ( mysqli_effected_rows($dbc) == 1 ) {
        // make the table row 
        $output  = "<tr>\n";
        $output .= "  <td><input type='checkbox' name='' value='' class='' />&nbsp;&nbsp;$name</td>\n";
        $output .= "  <td>$address</td>\n";
        $output .= "  <td>$city</td>\n";
        $output .= "  <td><span class='edit_ico'></span></td>\n";
        $output .= "  <td><span class='delete_ico'></span></td>\n";
        $output .= "</tr>\n";   

        echo $output;

    } else {
        echo 'query error';
    }
} else {
    echo "error in post array";
}

?>
```

This is my table structure from user.php (main page)

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><input type='checkbox' class='selectAll' name='selectAll' value='' /> Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type='checkbox' name='' value='' class='' />&nbsp;&nbsp;sfdsfsdf</td>
  <td>fdsafasf</td>
  <td>dsfadasf</td>
  <td><span class='edit_ico'></span></td>
  <td><span class='delete_ico'></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type='checkbox' name='' value='' class='' />&nbsp;&nbsp;Tharanga Nuwan</td>
  <td>Alagala</td>
  <td>Ginigathena</td>
  <td><span class='edit_ico'></span></td>
  <td><span class='delete_ico'></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Can anybody tell how can I update my HTML table?

Thank you.

Comment: You do it in the AJAX routine's success function (where you now have the line `alert(data);`).  Whatever you ECHO from process.php is returned to you as a string. Just parse the string and use jQuery to update your table. If further questions, post more.

Comment: You'll probably do something like: `success: function(data) { $('#myTable').html(data); }` inside your jQuery/AJAX section.

Comment: @gibberish in my script its not going into `success: funciton(data){}

Comment: @cmt I tried it. but not working

Comment: If I uncomment alert(thrownError); from error function, then there is an alert saying `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character`

Comment: @TNK The way that AJAX should work is (1) user.php sends some data (via jQuery/AJAX) to process.php. (2) process.php returns new data back to user.php (3) The new data is received **in the success function of the AJAX routine** (in user.php) - nowhere else. All further processing involving this new data **must** take place inside that success function.

Comment: @TNK Here is a test: Do what I said in my answer (create the DIV inside a table row, and add teh `$('#yogibear').html(data);` line to your ajax success function.) --- Now, at the very top of process.php insert this line: `die("You got to here");` and run your page.

Comment: @gibberish I did according to you. but nothing happen. its always going to error function

Comment: @TNK Read up on the `dataType` property of jQuery's [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Per the API docs, `dataType` is ***The type of data that you're expecting back from the server***. According to your ajax call, you're ***expecting*** JSON, but ***receiving*** html. If jQuery can't parse the return value to it's the specified `dataType` properly (in this case parse the HTML to JSON), it's going to throw an exception and drop into the error callback. Set your `dataType` to `html`.

Comment: @War10ck Thanks for your comment. Now display inserted row only. others is disappeared from the table.

Comment: @TNK You must identify where you want to put the inserted row, and create a DIV (or other holder) in which to insert it -- see my answer for example. If other rows are disappearing from the table, is it because you are replacing them with the new data? If so, in users.php (as part of the initial code, where you display the table for the first time) create an empty table row in which to put the data you get back from AJAX.

Comment: @gibberish can we chat regarding this?

Comment: Please select a correct answer when ready to close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that `process.php` is outputting a table row. You will receive that row inside the success function of the AJAX routine.

All you need to do is have a DIV in your document where you will put it.

For example, I suggest removing the `<tr>` and `</tr>` tags from your output, and adding a DIV to the table row you want to update, placing the current information inside that DIV:

```
<tr>
  <div id="yogibear">
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='' value='' class='' />sfdsfsdf</td>
    <td>fdsafasf</td>
    <td>dsfadasf</td>
    <td><span class='edit_ico'></span></td>
    <td><span class='delete_ico'></span></td>
  </div><!--#yogibear-->
</tr>
```

IN YOUR AJAX:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: "process.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
        //dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 
            name: $('#name').val(), 
            address: $('#address').val(), 
            city: $('#city').val() 
        },
        success:function(data){
            $('#yogibear').html(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I just tried it. But my coding is going to the alert() in error function

Comment: [Please see my comment above about the `dataType` property...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176177/how-i-get-ajax-respond-result-back-to-main-page#comment-24871630)

Comment: @TNK You need to simplify your code until you get it working, then add stuff back in one by one. To begin, remove the error function. Just do what is in the example above, and make your process.php do nothing but `die("Here I am");`, which will echo out that phrase and quit. This will test that your AJAX is actually working and give you great peace of mind. By the way, if any answers or comments (such as War10ck's above suggestion) are helpful to you please upvote them. Costs nothing and helps everyone out.

Comment: @TNK Is your problem solved now?  If you are having more problems keep posting comments/replies.